# Monitor widgets to update button state

Tags: qt

There is a situation: for example I have a button in the complex dialog. I need to disable this button until other widgets (QLineEdit) are empty.

I think the best way to monitor widget's state is to use QTimer and special function to change button state:

```
void foo()
{
    if( !lineEdit1->text().isEmpty() && !lineEdit2->text().isEmpty() )
        btn->setEnabled( true )
    else
        btn->setEnabled( false );
}
```

Are there other ways to solve this problem?
May be using QAction is better, or it will be an overhead?

PS: I can't to use signals and slots, because observing widgets (panels with widgets) are created in the separate modules, and they don't know about dialog's slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is using the signal/slot mechanizm to trigger changes in the `QLineEdit`. For example:

Connect line edit's `textChanged` signal to the appropriate slot

```
connect(lineEdit1, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(onTextChanged(const QString &));
```

Slot implementation.

```
void onTextChanged(const QString &text)
{
    if( !text.isEmpty() )
        btn->setEnabled( true )
    else
        btn->setEnabled( false );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution for the most cases. But in my situation observing widgets are created in separate modules and they do not know, about slots of the parent dialog. So I can't to use signal and slots.

Comment: @YuriyVelichko, why cannot you? You can connect signals of one module with a slot into another and that will also work well.

Comment: A - is a parent dialog. It contains panel that formed in the client side. A->add_widget( B->createPanel() ); As you see B nothing know about A and it's slots. AND SHOULD NOT KNOW. So I can't to connect A's slots to B's widgets. But I can get  B's widgets in A to observe it properties. dynamic_cast<MyW*>( A )->mpLineEdit() ( and I need not only line edit, cheboxes too from different panels). i think is more properly to use one observer method in the A class rather than dozen of signal-slot pairs.

Comment: @YuriyVelichko, if you can get B's widgets, as you said, why simply do not implement your slots in `A` and connect B's widgets signals to them? And why do you need dozen signal-slot pairs? You need one pair per widget type, at least.